# c compiler commands for generating a winexe

Tags: c, winapi, exe, winexe

how do i instruct the C compiler (gcc &| cc) to make a "Windows executable" in command line? just like csc /t:winexe filename.cs in c#?

my goal is to create a GUI(winapi) based app without the console.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MinGW like package and do the build on windows platform? If not I'm afraid you can build PE image from Linux like environment directly, except you are using WINE.

Comment: yes i'm using MinGW on a windows platform(windows 8), i want to do my compiling in the command line.

Comment: Try to build native Windows GUI application with GCC, please refer to http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/win32-apps-with-mingw/